# Using Javascript to create a test environment on live website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, testing, environment

I'm currently working in the backend of a Salesforce Desk platform, trying to code dependent dropdown menus. They use what are called Case-Themes which basically renders the layout for a client-interfacing page. The problem is, when I create my own Test Case-Theme, I can't preview it without publishing it and making it live.

My question is, if I were to use Javascript to create a conditional based on parameter values, is this a valid way to publish a live theme without messing up the front-end view/functionality.

```
<body>
<!-- Okay to Edit - Test Area -->
<div class="test_wrapper">
    <div class="test_header">
        <h1>DEVELOPMENT MODE</h1>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="test_body">
        <h2>Development Header</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="test_footer">
        <h2>Development Header</h2>
        <p>Voluptate necessitatibus inventore explicabo blanditiis veniam odio.</p>
        <div id="test_button">Click</div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elitinventore eligendi.</p>
        <br>
        <h2>Development SubSubHeading</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur quis veritatis.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#test_button').click(function(){
            alert('You are currently in Test Mode');
        });
    </script>
</div>
<!-- End Test Area -->

<!-- Don't Touch - Live Area -->
<div class="live_wrapper">
    <div class="live_header">
        <h1>Live Mode</h1>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="live_body">
        <h2>Live Subheading </h2>
        <p>Lorem nis placeat vitae in qui iste laborum sequi ea.</p>
        <p>Lorem delectus possimus ipsam ex, doloribus placeat. Perspiciatis.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="live_footer">
        <h2>Live Subheading </h2>
        <p>Lorem veniam tempore provident minima, consequuntur. Qui iure blanditiis veniam odio.</p>
        <div id="live_button">Click</div>
        <p>Lorem vero illum necessitatibus iste rem pariatur quos autem inventore eligendi.</p>
        <br>
        <h2>Live SubSubHeading </h2>
        <p>Lorem tus porro eligendi autem optio facilis quis veritatis.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#live_button').click(function(){
            alert('You are currently in Live Mode');
        });
    </script>
</div>
<!-- End Live Area -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if (window.location.search.indexOf('mode=test') > -1) {
            $('.live_wrapper').hide();
            $('.test_wrapper').css('display', 'block');
            } else {
            $('.test_wrapper').hide();
            $('.live_wrapper').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
</script>
```

As you already know, unless the URL has `?mode=test` the live code should render. Can someone please point out the dangers/drawbacks of doing something like this?

Comment: You would want to hide `test_wrapper` with inline CSS as well, or it may display briefly before the JS runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dark Falcon said in a comment, it will show briefly while it waits for the JavaScript to fire. I would suggest adding a class to the body tag that JS adds in test mode and then you can do something like this:

```
body.test .live_wrapper {
   display: none;
}
body.test .test_wrapper {
   display: block;
}
body .live_wrapper {
   display: block;
}
body .test_wrapper {
   display: none;
}
```

This will basically set the live mode as the default until you set the class of the body to "test"

```
if (window.location.search.indexOf('mode=test') > -1) {
   $('body').addClass('test');
}
```

Of course unless you're planning on changing between these on the fly, it would probably be better to turn these on or off with server-side code, assuming you are using one.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use CSS for this (using display:none on the containers you want to hide).
The only drawback for using a query parameter is that if users try, they can view your test-HTML. If that is not a problem then go for it.

Just make sure you dont expose any API's that someone can exploit.

Comment: Good point! I really doubt that anyone will be trying alter the URL to find out if there is a test mode, but still, thanks for pointing this out. I know I can't be too certain about what others are trying to do out there...